# Welche Präposition(en) passen zu dem Wort 'Fest'?

Tags: preposition

In verschiendenen Wörterbüchern sind unterschiedlichen Wörter mit "Fest" verbunden. Ich las An Fasching, zu und für Halloween.

Ich will sagen

> Sie hat sich scherzhaft (an/für/zu) Halloween als eine Zahnpastatube verkleidet.

Comment: Ich finde es verwirrend, dass im Titel und ersten Satz nach Präpositionen zum Wort "Fest" gefragt wird, während es dann eigentlich um die passende Präposition zum Wort "Halloween" geht.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Deinem Beispiel wären alle drei richtig.

> Sie hat sich scherzhaft **an** Halloween als eine Zahnpastatube verkleidet.

*An* meint hier ***an** diesem Tag*

> Sie hat sich scherzhaft **für** Halloween als eine Zahnpastatube verkleidet.

*Für* meint hier ***für** den Brauch an Hallowen*

> Sie hat sich scherzhaft **zu** Halloween als eine Zahnpastatube verkleidet.

*Zu* meint hier ***zu** dieser Gelegenheit*

Comment: Was den Inhalt deiner Antwort angeht, habe ich keine Einwände. Aber seit wann lässt du Übersetzungsanfragen ohne irgend einen Kommentar, worauf sich eine eventuelle Verwunderung bezüglich der in (nicht genannten) Wörterbüchern gefundenen Übersetzungen stützen würde, einfach so durchgehen? :o

Comment: On the general question, it seems like the only possible answer is, "it depends on context," which is certainly the the case in English: "I bought this costume for Mardi Gras." "This year I'm going to Mardi Gras." "I saw him at Mardi Gras."